# Symfony, how to use form event to validate dynamic client-side form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm using the select2 plugin with ajax to have a dynamic field on my form, but when i submit the it return me an error **"This value is not valid"**, which is normal cause i use the `ChoiceType` with an empty `array()` in the `choices` options on creation. According to [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-submitted-data) part of the symfony doc, the form event is my savior, so trying to use it but it look like something wrong with my code and can't really see what.

**So My Question Is :**

HOW to pass the choices possibility to the field, for the form to be valid.

**My form Type**

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            //My other field

        //My functions to add the field with the possible choices
        $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, $imageValue) use ($options) {
            if ($imageValue !== null) {
                $listImages = $this->getChoiceValue($imageValue, $options);

                if (!$listImages) {
                    $form->get('image')->addError(new FormError(
                    'Nous n\'avons pas pu trouver l\'image, veuiller choisir une autre'
                    ));
                }
            } else {
                $listImages = array();
            }

            //die(var_dump($listImages)); //Array of Image

            $form->add('image', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'id' => 'image'),
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => false,
                'choices' => $listImages));
        };

        $formModifierSubmit = function (FormInterface $form, $imageValue) use ($options) {
            if ($imageValue !== null) {
                $listImages = $this->getChoiceValue($imageValue, $options);

                if (!$listImages) {
                    $form->get('image')->addError(new FormError(
                        'Nous n\'avons pas pu trouver l\'image, veuiller choisir une autre'
                    ));
                }
            } else {
                $form->get('image')->addError(new FormError(
                    'Veuillez choisir une image s.v.p.'
                ));
            }

            //die(var_dump($listImages)); //Array of Image object

            $config = $form->get('image')->getConfig();
            $opts = $config->getOptions();
            $chcs = array('choices' => $listImages);
            //die(var_dump($chcs)); //output an array with a 'choices' keys with array value
            array_replace($opts, $chcs); //not work
            //array_merge($opts, $chcs); //not work
            //die(var_dump($opts)); //replacements/merge are not made
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // this would be the entity Article
                $data = $event->getData();

                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getImage());
            }
        );

        //$builder->get('image')->addEventListener( //give error cause the field image don't exist
        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifierSubmit) {
                $imageVal = $event->getData();
                //die(var_dump($imageVal)); //return all the submitted data field in an array
                //But when change this event to Submit it return the Article model populated by the submitted data, EXCEPT the image field which have null as value

                $formModifierSubmit($event->getForm(), $imageVal['image']);
            }
        );
    }

    public function getChoiceValue($imageValue, $options)
    {
        $listImages = $options['em']->getRepository('AlmotivAppBundle:Image')->findBy(array(
            'id' => $imageValue
        ));

        return $listImages; //array of Image object
    }
    [...]
}
```

**For Info**

My `image` field is not depending on any other field like the doc example, so i need to populate the `choices` options on `PRE_SUBMIT` event to give the possible choice.

And also `image` have a ManyToOne relation in my `Article` entity

```
class Article implements HighlightableModelInterface
{
    //some properties
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Image\Entity\Path", cascade={"persist"})
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $image;
}
```

If i'm in the bad way let me know cause i'm out of idea now, i try much thing, like

- array_replace with the options in the configuration of the field but didn't wrong.
- make an ajax request to the url of the form action `url : $form.attr('action')`, i think it will load the `choices` option with the possible of `<option>` but my select is still returned with none `<option>`.

and much more (can't remmenber).

And also i'm using the v3.1 of the framework with the v4.0.3 of the select2 plugin, if need more info just ask and thx for reading and trying help.

**Edit**

Just add some info to be more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You making things way too complicated. In your documentation example they add eventListener for already existing form field ('sport') and you are adding it to only later added field which does not exist (your 'image' field and 'position' field from the documentation example).

You should use [EntityType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) and if you need (which I'm not if sure you are) filter your images using [query_builder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities) option, for validation add [constraints](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#constraints) ([example with controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/without_class.html)).

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType {
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

         // $builder
         // My other field
         $imageFieldFunction = $this->getImageFieldFunction();

         $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, $imageFieldFunction);
         $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, $imageFieldFunction);

    }
    private function getImageFieldFunction()
    {
         return function(FormEvent $event) {
             $form = $event->getForm();
             $data = $event->getData();
             //when your data_class is Article 
             $image = $data->getImage();//depending on your Article class
             /*if you are using data_class => null
             $image = $data['image'];
              */
             $imageId = $image ? $image->getId() : 0;

             $builder->add('image', EntityType::class , array(
            'class' => 'AlmotivAppBundle:Image',
             'attr' => array(
                'id' => 'image'
             ) ,
             'expanded' => false,
             'multiple' => false,
             'constraints' => new NotBlank(),
             'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($imageId) {
                  return $er->createQueryBuilder('i')
                            ->where('i.id = :image_id')
                            ->setParameter('image_id', $imageId);
             }

         ));
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't think using `EntityType` is the best way. I have a field image on my form who have a ManyToOne relation with my Article entity, but the image table may have thousands entry, so i use ajax (with the select2 plugin) to pass the choices possibility on client side, and as i'm using an empty array in the choices option of the field, then i want to pass the choices to the field for the form to be valid

Comment: Well you can do your ajax loading with EntityType aswell. I've actually had this problem myself and the way I do it is by adding eventListener to builder for PRE_SET_DATA and PRE_SUBMIT events. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It work for me, i'm sure i was doing something like this way, but anyway it work perfectly. So the thing is to work wit the EntityType, and i was on the way, i mean i think. I post an answer wit my final code. Thx for help

Comment: my bad it seem i can't post answer, i make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/LastKhode/a224e3ba2030d31e0af7f203ad6b0189)