# Symfony 3 - Dynamic Form - ChoiceType Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, forms, symfony, events

I am currently working on a user creation form.

A user has a profile attribute:

```
    /**
     * Many Users have One profile
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProjectBundle\Entity\User\Profile", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="profile_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $profile;
```

This profile is chosen according to another select (on change action jquery) :

```
{% autoescape  'html'%}
        {{ '<script id="tmpl_user_profile" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
                <option value="${id}">${libelle}</option>
        </script>'|raw }}
{% endautoescape  %}

    <script>
        $('select#user_organisationMember').on('change',function(){
            var value = this.value;
            if (value == '') {
                $('#user_profile').empty();
            }
            var urlAjax = "{{ path('admin_user_get_profile', { 'entity': "value" }) }}";
            $.ajax({
                url: urlAjax.replace("value",value),
                method: "post"
            }).done(function(msg){
                $('#user_profile').empty();
                $('#tmpl_user_profile').tmpl(JSON.parse(msg)).appendTo('#user_profile');
            }) ;
        });
    </script>
```

Until then everything worked correctly ! 
The different profiles in the select tag changes well according to the other select.

Upon arrival on the page, I want the list of profiles to be empty.

So I adapted my form using Symfony's FormEvent.

This is my first use of FormEvent, I may have made a mistake!

My FormType :

```
/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('lastname')
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('gender',null,array('required'=>true))
            ->add('organisationMember',null,array(
                'required' => true,
                'choices' => $options['organisation'],
                'group_by' => 'type_organisation',
                'placeholder' => 'Choisissez votre organisation'
            ))
            ->add('job')
            ->add('mobile')
            ->add('phone')
            ->add('alert_failure')
            ->add('alert_full')
            ->add('alert_other')
            ->add('plainPassword', TextType::class, array('required' => true))
            ->add('email')
            ->add('profile', null, array(
                'required' => true,
            ));

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $entity = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            if (!$entity || null === $entity->getId()) {
                $form->remove('profile');
                $form->add('profile', ChoiceType::class);
            }
        });
    }
```

By default all the profiles of my database are loaded in the select to not get the error 'This value is incorrect'.

But I do not want the user to see all the profiles, so I remove it in the event and return the field empty.

But I still get the error 'This value is incorrect' because actually, since the base select is empty, the form does not found the value entered.

I would like to have a select which by default is empty, which is filled in Ajax and which does not show me the error 'This value is incorrect'.

How can I please do it?
Thanks

Comment: is `profile` a member of your Entity with a foreign key relationship, or is it not connected to your database?

Comment: There is a foreign key relationship

Comment: Have you tried setting `data => null` in your `'profile'` form options?

Comment: It does not change anything

Comment: Try setting `data => null` while also removing your event listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very simple solution, I do not know if it's a good idea, but it takes not a lot of lines.

I have delivered the default form

```
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('lastname')
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('gender',null,array('required'=>true))
            ->add('organisationMember',null,array(
                'required' => true,
                'choices' => $options['organisation'],
                'group_by' => 'type_organisation',
                'placeholder' => 'Choisissez votre organisation'
            ))
            ->add('job')
            ->add('mobile')
            ->add('phone')
            ->add('alert_failure')
            ->add('alert_full')
            ->add('alert_other')
            ->add('plainPassword', TextType::class, array('required' => true))
            ->add('email')
            ->add('profile', null, array(
                'required' => true,
                'placeholder' => 'Choose an organisation !',
            ));
    }
```

And on my view:

```
<div class="form-group{% if form.profile.vars.errors|length %} has-error{% endif %}">
        <label for="{{ form.profile.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right required">Profile(s) </label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            {% do form.profile.setRendered %}
            <select name="user[profile]" id="user_profile" required class="form-control">
             //We can do a loop if needed
            </select>
            {{ form_errors(form.profile) }}
        </div>
</div>
```

This way I fully manage whether or not I want information in my select.

And it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add field not only on PRE_SET_DATA, but also on PRE_SUBMIT event. Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619386/symfony-how-to-use-form-event-to-validate-dynamic-client-side-form/44640130#44640130) on similar question.