# Symfony form select2 ajax entities

Tags: json, ajax, symfony, jquery-select2

I have a form field which is of type EntityType and it contains multiple towns. I want these towns to be obtained via Ajax remotely so I created a json request which returns the Towns I am looking for.

These towns return their id and name. The problem is they are not treated as Town entities, so the Form is not validated.

Form field:

```
->add('towns', EntityType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'mapped' => false,
            'label' => 'Towns',
            'translation_domain' => 'forms',
            'class' => Town::class,
            'choices' => [],
            'multiple' => true,
            'placeholder' => 'Select towns'
])
```

Select javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.townDynamicSelect').select2({
            minimumInputLength: 2,
            ajax: {
                url: '{{ path('app_getTowns') }}',
                dataType: 'json',
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                text: item.name,
                                id: item.id
                            }
                        })
                    };
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Json response:

```
public function getTowns(Request $request, TownRepository $townRepository){
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() && !is_null($this->getUser())) {
        $term = $request->query->get('term');
        $towns = $townRepository->findMaxByInitials($term, 20);
        return $this->json($towns, 200, [], [
            'groups' => ['town_select'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine until I select the towns I want and I submit the form. I get this error:

```
Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException

Unable to reverse value for property path "[towns]": Could not find all matching choices for the given values.
```

This is how the select block looks like after adding the towns.

```
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="6" style="width: 1483px;">
   <span class="selection">
     <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false">
     <ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
        <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Town1" data-select2-id="32"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Town1</li>
        <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Town2" data-select2-id="33"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Town2</li>
        <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline"><input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="searchbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="" style="width: 0.75em;"></li>
     </ul>
     </span>
  </span>
  <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
```

Edit: this is what I've tried so far

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $towns = $form->get('towns')->getData();

        $field = $form->get('towns');
        $options = $field->getConfig()->getOptions();

        $options['choices'] = $towns;

        $form->add('towns', EntityType::class, $options);
        $form->get('towns')->setData($towns);
    });
```

Comment: How look your select in html code after update by ajax ?

Comment: @threeside Added in post

Comment: @msg Any examples?

Comment: Look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44826983) and one [of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639112#56647678).

Comment: @msg In my particular case I need the options to be updated every time user types in the select bar, because options may not be the same. Is there a way I can create a custom event?

Comment: @AwesomeGuy Use your controller function to retrieve the data and send it in json as you are, the problem is that when the form component maps the request to the form and tries to validate the ids don't match, because `choices` is empty. You need to get the data before mapping, load the entities and modify the `town` field to change `choices` to those values. Have you made any progress at all? If so, [edit] your question to include your current problem. But look at my linked answer it's pretty much that, `PRE_SET_DATA` / `PRE_SUBMIT`.

Comment: @msg I added what I have done so far. It's still not working.

Comment: But `$towns` at that point is still a scalar, right? You need to load the entities manually via the repository and assign that to `choices`, and you shouldn't need to call `setData`. It really is covered in other answers, but let me know if you get it running, otherwise I'll try to put together a fully working project that fits this.